# Did they reuse the same background actor in two separate scenes in "Forrest Gump"?

Tags: forrest-gump

Am I correct in claiming that in Forrest Gump (1994):

- Chopper's pilot in Vietnam scene, sitting next to Bubba and Forrest (00:40:42) and
- Drug taker in Jenny's New Year Eve's scene (01:29:49)

are both played by the same background actor?

[image]

Or is this just a coincidence and both "three seconds" roles are played by two different, simply looking very similar actors?

Comment: Did you check the credits somewhere? Maybe it's mentioned

Comment: **Pictures?** It's actually quite easy to be in a movie or show as two characters, but not normally if they're really close enough to camera to be recognisable [it does happen, though]. A supporting artist [extra] wouldn't usually get a movie credit so 30 years later this may be next to impossible to find out.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'll try to add some pictures, if I manage to extract ones. But to be honest, community of this site again makes me feel sad. Two questions, two downvotes, zero explanation on what is wrong. I though that Movies has already left "kindergarten" beta of downvoting questions without expressing any reason.

Comment: @OldPadawan Didn't check, honestly. But for the actor that appears two times for three seconds I wouldn't expect it to appear. Some sources says that an actor must appear for at least half a minute and speak at least 5-10 sentences to be considered for credits (not necessary: to be surely mentioned there). This one say nothing in neither of his three-seconds scenes.

Comment: Getting a credit is usually in your contract before you start, as a day player [actor]. I'm a [very occasional] actor but usually an SA [extra]. Once in the last decade, I've been 'promoted' from SA to a credit, when I got my own lines & close-ups in a scene. I didn't actually discover it until I went to the movie premier… though that in itself may have been a hint - I've never been invited to a premier before or since;)

Comment: I've punched some brightness into the pics. It's hard to tell but I'd say 'not the same person'. Once you ignore the fashionable tash, left guy has lumpier nose & pointier chin. Couldn't call it if there was money involved, but for free I'd say 'no match'.

Comment: @Tetsujin Reading your comment (and Valorum's answer below) and looking at these _still_ pictures, I'd say that you are correct. Looking at the same as _three seconds flashes_ (in movie), I'd be more than sure that this is the same actor -- even though I watched "Forrest Gump" 30+ times so far. Hence the question.

Comment: @Tetsujin - In this instance, the entire cast seems to get a credit, regardless of their prominence. Unless you're a genuine background nobody

Comment: @Valorum - interesting. Some productions have been known to do that - I've even seen a couple where all the SAs were credited too - but it's rare.

Comment: trejder - I didn't downvote, but identification questions (actors or locations) are not allowed and usually get closed, so my guess is that someone thought that's what this is. But technically you are not asking who the actor is, you are asking about the use of actors in this film. Although as seen in the answer by @Valorum, looking at the names in the credits can be used to determine whether or not it was the same actor, so I guess that's creeping right up to the line and living dangerously.

Comment: @Tetsujin - an interesting piece of trivia related to your comment about getting credit only the time that you had spoken lines, in an episode of Get Smart (season 4 episode 25), in the credits there is a character identified as "Old Timer" with the actor's name listed as William Yarmy. However in the episode he was just an extra in a group of several men and didn't have any lines, and so would not normally have been credited. In this case the extra was Don Adams' father. Don Adams' real name was Donald Yarmy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helpfully, the film has a cast listed *by order of appearance*.

> The *'Helicopter Gunman'* was played by [Daniel Gilhooly](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109830/characters/nm0319375).
>
> [image]

> The *'Drugged out boyfriend'* was played by [Matt Rebenkoff](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0714288/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t98)
>
> [image]

You can see Matt in his only other credited role, as 'Security Guard' in Anchorman 2

> [image]

Comment: Given the pictures, I am really, really surprised to find out that these are two different actors. Is it only me, or both pictured in my question looks really very similar?

Comment: @trejder - It's just you.

Comment: @trejder : to me, eyebrows, nose and chin seem really different. Just an opinion though...

Comment: @trejder - I wasn't able to tell them apart, at least not enough to make a for sure determination that it wasn't the same person. But I don't rate my identification skills as being at the top level, so I don't know how much of a data point that is, other than you aren't the only one.